# How to declare an array of pointers to member functions in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I am doing a small project using arduino and I need to use an array of methods.

I've tried doing what I would normally do in C# / Java but that didn't work. I went online and tried many different examples and I kept getting lead to the same error message.

```
class ColourSensor{

public:
  void (*routine[3])() = {
        routine0,
        routine1,
        routine2
    };

  void routine0();
  void routine1();
  void routine2();
};
```

When I compile I get the following error:

`cannot convert 'ColourSensor::routine0' from type 'void (ColourSensor::)()' to type 'void (*)()'`

Comment: Array of `std::function<void(void)>` and filling with lambdas doesn't work?

Comment: Pointers to member functions and pointers to static/free function are different things. Which ones are you trying to use?

Comment: In C++ there is a difference between member functions and free functions. Your list can only store free functions, but you are trying to put member functions into it.

Comment: I can change them to static, there only needs to be one instance.

Comment: @MaxLanghof How would I change them to free functions?

Comment: @unprotested By moving them out of the class they are in. It appears that you are trying to write Java/C# code in C++, which is not going to get you very far. You should obtain a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start from the beginning, because you can't really learn C++ by trial and error.

Comment: *I've tried doing what I would normally do in C# / Java but that didn't work* -- Advice -- **Never** do this.  Do not use other languages to figure out how to do something in C++.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I know very little about C++ lol

Comment: @unprotested I accidentally hit enter and posted my comment too soon. Please see the edit.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Noted. Although so far with arduino I've coded entirely with my knowledge from C# and thought it was C# for a long time. I recently learned when I tried doing this that is was more similar to C++.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik arduino does't have the C++ standard library

Comment: please create a [mcve]. It looks like those are class methods and not free functions.

Comment: @bolov I have edited my original post.

Comment: If you make the functions `static`, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Things get complicated because they are methods. A method has an implicit hidden `this` parameter, so it's a different type than a free functions.

This is the correct syntax:

```
class ColourSensor
{
public:
    using Routine = void (ColourSensor::*)();

    Routine routines[3] = {
        &ColourSensor::routine0,
        &ColourSensor::routine1,
        &ColourSensor::routine2,
    };

    void routine0();
    void routine1();
    void routine2();

    void test()
    {
        // calling syntax:
        (this->*routines[0])();
    }  
};
```

An alternative which simplifies the calling syntax using non-capturing lambdas (which can decay to function pointer):

```
class ColourSensor
{
public:
    using Routine = void (*)(ColourSensor*);

    Routine routines[3] = {
        [](ColourSensor* cs) { return cs->routine0(); },
        [](ColourSensor* cs) { return cs->routine1(); },
        [](ColourSensor* cs) { return cs->routine2(); }
    };

    void routine0();
    void routine1();
    void routine2();

    void test()
    {
        // simpler calling syntax
        routines[0](this);
    }  
};
```

Going one step further (and off the rails), if you know you always use `this` object to call the methods you need to capture `this` in lambda. The problem now is that capturing lambdas can't decay to function pointers and since every lambda is a different type you can't store them in an array. The usual solution in C++ is type erasure with `std::function`. Unfortunately arduino C++ environment doesn't have the C++ standard library (because of the size constraints). For reference, this is how it would have looked (and since we are using the standard library, we use `std::array`):

```
/// !! not working in Arduino !!

#include <functional>
#include <array>

class ColourSensor
{
public:
    std::array<std::function<void(void)>, 3> routines = {
        [this]() { return this->routine0(); },
        [this]() { return this->routine1(); },
        [this]() { return this->routine2(); }
    };

    void routine0();
    void routine1();
    void routine2();

    void test()
    {
        // simple calling syntax
        routines[0]();
    }  
};
```

There is a workaround for this. And although it's a bit of work to setup, it's actually faster than the `std::function` because we don't use type erasure:

```
class ColourSensor;

class Routine
{
private:
    using R = void (ColourSensor::*)();
    R routine_;
    ColourSensor* calling_obj_;

public:
    Routine(R routine, ColourSensor* calling_obj)
        : routine_{routine}, calling_obj_{calling_obj}
    {}

    void operator()();
};

class ColourSensor
{
public:
    Routine routines[3] = {
        Routine{&ColourSensor::routine0, this},
        Routine{&ColourSensor::routine1, this},
        Routine{&ColourSensor::routine2, this}
    };

    void routine0();
    void routine1();
    void routine2();

    void test()
    {
        // simple calling syntax
        routines[0]();
    }  
};

void Routine::operator()() { return (calling_obj_->*routine_)(); }
```

---

If however your routines don't use the state of the `ColourSensor`, than you can make them static functions:

```
class ColourSensor
{
public:
    using Routine = void (*)();

    Routine routines[3] = {
        routine0,
        routine1,
        routine2,
    };

    static void routine0();
    static void routine1();
    static void routine2();

    void test()
    {
        routines[0]();
    }  
};
```

Comment: +1 for the `using`. That’s a too often neglected requirement for keeping your sanity when dealing with function pointers, especially *member* function pointers.